# Error when trying to run Hadoop after a new install

Tags: windows, hadoop, windows-10

I've just painstakingly followed detailed instructions on how to install Hadoop on Windows 10. I have set the `*_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables correctly. Hadoop is in the path as when I enter `hadoop` it seems to start running, but gives me this message:

```
\Hadoop\hadoop-3.1.3\bin\ was unexpected at this time.
```

I have just followed the installation instructions carefully twice, and both installations were identical, so I didn't make a mistake on the second installation, I hope.

What could this error message mean, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Which instruction did you followed. Can you share that link with us?

Comment: And also I want to know is your java is 32-bit or 64-bit type

Comment: @Kalana The install instructions are 3 pages of an ebook called Practical Machine Learning, and it would be impractical to cite them here.

Comment: @Kalana I don' t use Java myself, so I don't know what bit type my installation is. How can I tell?